# How to get data from parent table through child table

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I want to get all the product name that has been ordered and stored in OrderItem table and I want to sum their quantity group by product name. Help!!!

Here are my tables.

```
class m_Product(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
Brand = models.CharField(max_length=200)
quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
digital = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)
image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
description = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
tags = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class OrderItem(models.Model):
product = models.ForeignKey(
    m_Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
order = models.ForeignKey(
    Prescription, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


s = m_Product.objects.select_related('orderitem').filter('name').values('quantity').annotate(sum = Sum('quantity'))
```

Comment: Do products have a unique name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can annotate the `m_PRoduct` with the `Sum` of the `quantity`s of the related `OrderItem`s with:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

m_Product.objects.annotate(
    total_ordered=Sum('orderitem__quantity')
)
```

The `m_Product`s that arise from this will have an extra attribute `.total_ordered` which contains the sum of the `quantity` of the related `OrderItem`s.

This will also contain `m_Product`s that have not been ordered at all. We can omit these products with:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

m_Product.objects.filter(
    orderitem__isnull=False
).annotate(
    total_ordered=Sum('orderitem__quantity')
)
```

If products have no unique name, it thus means that the same product name can occur multiple times with different `total_ordered`. But usually that is not a problem: we want to know the total amount of orders of a product, not the total amount of orders of products that somehow have the same name, since sometimes for the same name there are different products.

If you really want to obtain the sum of the quantities per product name, we can work with:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

m_Product.objects.values('name').filter(
    orderitem__isnull=False
).annotate(
    total_ordered=Sum('orderitem__quantity')
).order_by('name')
```